# http redirects and seo

Tags: http, redirect, iis-7.5

I have been asked to make all requests for sitename.com be redirected to www.sitename.com to prevent duplicate content and to make all https pages have a canonical link to a http page again to prevent duplicate content.

Is that actually necessary?

If it is how can I easily set up a redirect in IIS7.5. I tried but the site went down with the old too many redirects error.

I'm stumped at the moment i'm sure by now if every site had to do this asp.net would of built it in to the framework to add canonical links to any page served securely.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary, but is necessarily better that splitting your Googlejuice between two *different* URLs.

IIS7 pretty much has this built in for you:

- Open IIS
- Select the website
- Select 'URL Rewrite'
- Click 'Add Rule(s)'
- Select 'Canonical domain name'
- Click 'OK'
- Type in the primary domain name
- Click 'OK'

Comment: Well this has indeed made the SEO guy very happy.  This isn't exactly a redirect is it, so has it also solved the https issue?